# How to append to the table which is created dynamically .

Tags: jquery

i am creating a table from a JSON Array .

Once the table is created , i want to append note the table as shown in this below link

http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/us-economic-calendar.aspx

(At the bottom of the page , right hand side )

you will find this

**Market Moving Indicator**

**Merit Extra Attention**

I want to do the same to be table

This is my code

```
function displayfruitsdata()
{
    var itemshtml = '<table class="table table-striped">';
        for (var i = 0; i < fruitsdata.length; i++)
        {
            var decideclass = fruitsdata[i].color;
            if (decideclass === 'red')
            {
                decideclass = 'indicator_red';
            }
            else if (decideclass === 'green')
            {
                decideclass = 'indicator_green';
            }
            else
            {
                decideclass = 'empty';
            }

            itemshtml += ' <tr>\
            <td>' + fruitsdata[i].name + '</td>\
            <td class="'+decideclass+'">' + fruitsdata[i].color + '</td>\
        </tr>';
        }
        itemshtml += '</table>';

    $("#divdata").html(itemshtml);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5wk8twvb/5/

Could you please tell me how to append to the table after table is created .

Comment: For example: `$("#table").append("<tr><td> Strawberry </td><td class='indicator_red'> red </td>");`

Comment: please see this jsfiddle , http://jsfiddle.net/5wk8twvb/9/ its not appending .

Comment: Because your table has a different id. Change `id="mytable"` to `id="table"`

Comment: I think I did not understand you correctly. You want to add just the note after the table, not a row to the table itself, right?

Answer (score 0):

You may either:

- store `itemshtml` in outer/global scope, append to it and then call `$("#divdata").html(itemshtml);` again, or
- use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to `$("#divdata").append(newItemsHtml)` after you stored the markup you want to append in your `newItemsHtml`.

Answer (score 0):

$(".table").append("New");

or u can add id to the table if u have more than table class

$("#mtable").append("New");